# Left Shift of String Array by Specified position

Tags: java, string

I was asked to answer a question of String Array to shift array elements in left by specified position.
Question is as below:

```
String str[]={"A", "B","C","D","E","F"};
```

Answer should be as below:

```
String str[]={"D","E","F","A", "B","C",};
```

How to do this using Java String?

Comment: Whether the array contains Strings, Integers or Bananas doesn't change anything. You should realize this first. Then try something.

Comment: Try with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I will not take your much time..

Solution:

in simple thinking the way which comes in our mind is first input the elements in array and then shift each element until our predicate output comes.

But if you want more efficient solution then
It is better to store the array element directly in shifted form rather then simple thinking.

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    //take input in shifted form
    array[ (i + distance) % array.length ] = sc.next().charAt(0);

    //for distance read below
    //sc is Scanner object
    // array is the name of the array 
}
```

**Distance**

if you want right shift operation then it will be positive (i.e. int distance=2 )

if you want left shift operation then it will be negative
and if you want to avoid it then in the code you can do this.

```
array[ (i-distance) % array.length ] = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
String str[]={"A", "B","C","D","E","F"};
int shifby= 3;

for (int i = 0; i < shifby; i++) {
    for (int j = str .length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        String temp = str [j];
        str [j] = str [j - 1];
        str [j - 1] = temp;
        }
}

//Printing array
for (int j=0;j <= str .length - 1;  j++) {
        System.out.println((str[j]));
        }
// System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way I could do it!

```
String str[] = {"A", "B","C","D","E","F"};

public static String[] shiftLeft(String[] arr, int n){
    String newArray = new String[shiftLeft.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < shiftLeft.length; i++){
        newArray[i] = arr[(i + n) % (shiftLeft.lenght + 1)];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

To use it you do:

```
str = shiftLeft(str, 3);
```